# onedrive oauth2 redirect_uri for android app

Tags: android, onedrive

I am trying to make an android app login to onedrive using the new REST API, Retrofit, and OAUTH2. I have it working: I can contact the auth server and get a response. The question: is there any way in onedrive to set up a custom scheme for the redirect_uri? As far as I can tell the developer console insists that I use "http" or "https", both of which force my users to go through an app picker to handle the auth response from onedrive. If I could enter a custom scheme or even "oauth2" as a scheme then that hassle could be avoided.

FWIW: this is not a problem for dropbox. They let me specify whatever URL I want, including those with custom schemes.

And yes, I know I could do it myself in a webview, but that brings along a number of other problems such as handling stored passwords and cookies.

Comment: I actually wrote a sample application for the OneDrive API, https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-explorer-android you might want to use that as a starting point, as it has an OAuth implementation inside it

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

I don't want to use the Microsoft libraries, but instead use the base REST implementation. To do that I must supply a "redirect_uri" to the Microsoft App Console. That redirect_uri must begin with http: or https:. which means that I cannot use custom schemes which means that the user will be presented with a Chooser when the redirect uri is returned. Not a huge deal but it is difficult to explain to users.

I have it working using https: as the scheme.

Comment: @PeterNied is there any way to just include the authenticate component from your app so I don't have to duplicate the code to establish a onedrive connection?

Comment: We are building an Android SDK for the OneDrive APIs that will provide a lightweight solution for authentication and the application interfaces of OneDrive, it will be available via gradle and maven library.  Stay tuned at https://dev.onedrive.com for updates

Comment: @PeterNied what do you suggest I do in the mean time?

Comment: You can fork the codebase and slim it down to just what you need

Comment: @PeterNied is there a way to just compile a .jar and add it?

Comment: @PeterNied is there an ETA on the SDK?